# DynamoDB list_append work in console get error in node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

In my case when I have execute this in my console:

`aws dynamodb update-item --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000 --table-name testing --key '{"id": {"N": "4"}}' --update-expression 'SET cosas = list_append(cosas,:s)' --expression-attribute-values '{":s":{"L":[{"N":"8778789"}]}}'`

works with out any problem, but when I try the same in node with the code:

```
var params = {
  "TableName": "testing",
  "Key": {
    "id": {
        "N": "4"
    }
  },
  "UpdateExpression": "SET #attrName = list_append(#attrName,:attrValue)",
  "ExpressionAttributeNames" : {
    "#attrName" : "cosas"
  },
  "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
    ":attrValue": {
        "L": [
            {
                "N": "1489401606520"
            }
        ]
    }
 }
};
```

I get this error:

```
Unable to add log G030JF053195HW66:SINGLE . Error JSON: {
  "message": "Invalid attribute value type",
  "code": "ValidationException",
  "time": "2017-03-15T09:03:45.642Z",
  "requestId": "f04532d2-44c5-48a7-8758-3f7012aaae22",
  "statusCode": 400,
  "retryable": false,
  "retryDelay": 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [update](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#update-property) method when using the JS document client. A method called `updateItem` does not exist in the document client.

Comment: Thank Alex for your replay. I edit the question because I pasted an incorrect error....my mistake. Can you help me with this correct error?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me: -

You don't need to specify types explicitly e.g. "L" or "M" when using the `aws-sdk` in `nodejs`. For the expression attribute values, `aws-sdk` automatically infers them using the type of value being passed through, e.g. if you pass an array, it assumes that it is a list, if you pass in an `{}`, it assumes that it is a map. `aws-sdk` will process your current params in a very convoluted way. Tip: When in doubt, enable logging in `aws-sdk` like this:

```
AWS.config.logger = console;
```

Therefore, in your specific case, these would be the modified params:-

```
var params = {
      "TableName": "testing",
      "Key": {
        "id": 4
      },
      "UpdateExpression": "SET #attrName = list_append(if_not_exists(#attrName, 
          :empty_list), :attrValue)",
      "ExpressionAttributeNames" : {
        "#attrName" : "cosas"
      },
      "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
        ":attrValue": [1489401606520],
        ":empty_list": []
     }
    };
```

These params will tell AWS to:

- Create an empty list if "cosas" list does not exist
- Add the value 1489401606520 to the cosas list

Good luck.